# whats the significance between having the java class containing the main method setup as public and not

Tags: java

When I started learning Java I too started with the ubiqutous Hello world app. Which is more or less like :

```
public class MyClass {

 public static void main(String args[]){

    //some code here....

 }

}
```

Its been many years since my tryst with Java but recently I was confronted by a beginner with a problem : Her class file wouldn't run even though she was able to compile correctly.

After looking at her code the first thing I noticed was that is didn't have the public access specifier on the class with the main method. I immediately mocked her on that slip up and went about "fixing" it by adding the public access modifier. The joke was on me offcourse as that didn't make any difference either. I then realized that she was trying to execute the compiled class from a different directory from the one where the class file was. I changed to that dir and issued the java command and it ran immediately.

This brings me to my question... Most hello world examples have the class setup with public access when its just as ok to not have that at all. So what difference does it make  if at all for a class that contains the main method ?

To help make it clearer as to what we were doing exactly here are the steps :

We had the class in

```
c:\users\[usersname]\[my documents folder]\myprog.class
```

and we tried to run it from c:\ (as our working dir) . We did specify the full relative path expecting it to work. like so :

```
java users\[usersname]\[my documents folder]\myprog
```

Offcourse this just failed untill I changed into the documents folder making it the current working dir and issuing the command again like so

```
java myprog
```

So basically such a call makes sense when you have the class in a package resembling the folder structure prepended to its name. In this case the class is not in any package.

Comment: I'm interested: are you saying that the program wouldn't execute from a different directory, even with the correct relative path to the class file?

Comment: Maybe an example will make what happened clear:
She had the compiled class file sitting in a here Documents dir.
But she was trying to exec the class using java from C: itself. She was offcourse typing in the full path to the file as the first param to the java executable. I then changed into the Documents dir and ran the java exec passing it the just the name. I ended up showing her an example of how folder names are appended to the class name when loading classes which are in a package (i guess this approach is for when one doesnt set the classpath) but not when they are not.

Comment: When you say:  *"from C: itself"* you mean the C programming language? or Windows C:\ directory?

Comment: (Given the context, I assume the Windows C:\ directory.) It would seem then that class visibility is respected when executing the main method, so that if visibility is limited to package only (the default if no other is specified) the command must be executed from within the same directory as the class

Comment: I meant from C: as in "C:\" drive( root folder on it) with the class in the user's "My Documents" folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "public" vs. "package" specifier has to do with whether classes in other packages are allowed to "see" the class.

Most hello world programs ignore packages, so they go with the more common public option. Most people never have to learn about other package specifiers (and their limitations) until they actually learn to organize their project into packages. Of course, if you have only one class, it doesn't matter either.

Also, I'm not sure why you mock novice programmers. I've been coding in Java for 10 years and still learn new things all the time.

Comment: Ahh  well call it a flaw in my character "code". Must try to debug and fix that in an update sometime in the near future. Thanks for your prompt answer.

Comment: You can invoke main from a non public class if it's in the claspath ... :-/ Probably I didn't get the OP

Answer (score 1):

Like any method, visibility to other classes is at stake.  Your main method will be accessible to other classes if you mark it public.

Comment: I was refering to the public access modifier on the CLASS not the function. Or maybe I read your answer the wrong way. I am aware that not marking the "main" function with public will prevent the jvm from calling it. My question what if any is the significance of making the CLASS "MyClass" in the example public or not as in both cases the file executes just fine.

Comment: @balien I misunderstood the question and Uri's answer is therefore more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> *So what difference does it make  if at all for a class that contains the main method ?*

It doesn't!

You can happly run the main method of a class with public access modifier or without it.

Your problem was, the class was in a different directory so, the interpreter ( java ) didn't knew where too look at.

Let's say I have:  `src/Hello.java`

And you compile it with: `javac src/Hello.java`

It compiles fine, and then you try to execute it: `java Hello`

but that won't run, not because  the class defined has public access or not, but because the generated `.class` file is inside the directory `src` and not right here ( `.` )

You can specify where do you want the .class files to be placed using the -d option.

See this example:

```
$mkdir src 
$cat >src/Hello.java <<.
> class Hello {
>     public static void main( String [] args ) {
>         System.out.println("Hello, world");
>     }
> }
> .
$javac src/Hello.java 
$java Hello 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
$cd src/
$java Hello 
Hello, world
$cd ..
$ls
src
$rm src/Hello.class 
$javac -d . src/Hello.java 
$java Hello 
Hello, world
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it really not required?  Interesting, I have to say that I haven't tried it.

Asides from whether the Java runtime can invoke your main class or not, the access modifiers on that class mean the same as they do for any other.  If a class is public, then other classes can reference it, whereas if its private they won't be able to (with of course protected and default being middle grounds).

Regardless of whether it's strictly necessary to make the main class public, it doesn't make any conceptual sense to do otherwise.  Narrower access definitions can be taken as signs that this class won't be accessed by external aspects, so you're free to change the definition as you see fit.  In this context, your main class is most definitely `public` and so I'd argue it would be wrong (even if legal) to define it as anything else.

Answer (score 0):

A visibility modifier (public, private, or protected) is actually optional.

When you don't specify a visibility modifier, default visibility applies.

Default visibility allows classes in the same package to access whatever it is that has default visibility (whether it's a class, method, or attribute)